# $\bar{T}(\bar{X})$ is closed if and only if $\bar{T}$ admits a continuous inverse?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading a textbook "Fredholm and Local Spectral Theory II: With Application to Weyl-type Theorems" and stuck with the proof of Theorem 1.2.

Let $T\in L(X,Y)$, $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Let $\bar{X}:=X/Ker(T)$ and denote by $\bar{T}:\bar{X} \rightarrow Y$ the continuous injection  corresponding to $T$ defined by 
$$\bar{T}\bar{x}:=Tx$$
And the textbook says "by a classical result of functional analysis, it is known that $\bar{T}(\bar{X})$ is closed if and only if  $\bar{T}$ admits a continuous inverse, i.e., there exists a constant $\delta>0$ such that $ \|\bar{T}\bar{x}\| \geq \delta \|\bar{x}\|$".
But I don't understand this statement. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\bar T$ has a continuous inverse, $\bar T$ is an homeomorphism between normed space, and $\bar T(\bar X)$ is Banach since $\bar X$ is Banach. 
If $\bar T(\bar X)$ is closed, $\bar T$ is a continuous and surjective,  the open map theorem implies that it is open, this implies that its inverse is continuous.